# Accumulo Tracer hangs on startup

Tags: hdfs, apache-zookeeper, ambari, accumulo

I am using Apache Ambari to manage HDFS, Zookeeper and Accumulo. I am having issues with Accumulo Tracer starting up.

Ambari starts Accumulo Tracer using this command.

```
Execute['cat /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/pass | ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server /usr/hdp/current/accumulo-client/bin/accumulo shell -u root -f /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/cmds'] {'not_if': 'ambari-sudo.sh su accumulo -l -s /bin/bash -c \'cat /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/pass0 | ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server /usr/hdp/current/accumulo-client/bin/accumulo shell -u root -e "userpermissions -u ambari-qa"\'', 'user': 'accumulo'}
```

However it hangs and Ambari times it out with this output with the command above being at the bottom.

```
stderr:   /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/errors-2808.txt

Python script has been killed due to timeout after waiting 180 secs
stdout:   /var/lib/ambari-agent/data/output-2808.txt

2018-08-22 20:06:47,356 - Stack Feature Version Info: Cluster Stack=2.6, Cluster Current Version=2.6.3.0-235, Command Stack=None, Command Version=2.6.3.0-235 -> 2.6.3.0-235
2018-08-22 20:06:47,374 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf
2018-08-22 20:06:47,513 - Stack Feature Version Info: Cluster Stack=2.6, Cluster Current Version=2.6.3.0-235, Command Stack=None, Command Version=2.6.3.0-235 -> 2.6.3.0-235
2018-08-22 20:06:47,521 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf
User Group mapping (user_group) is missing in the hostLevelParams
2018-08-22 20:06:47,522 - Group['livy'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,524 - Group['spark'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,525 - Group['zeppelin'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,526 - Group['hadoop'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,528 - Group['users'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,529 - Group['knox'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,530 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,531 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh hive'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,540 - call returned (0, '1001')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,540 - User['hive'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1001}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,542 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,542 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh zookeeper'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,552 - call returned (0, '1002')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,552 - User['zookeeper'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1002}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,553 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,554 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh infra-solr'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,562 - call returned (0, '1003')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,562 - User['infra-solr'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1003}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,564 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,564 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ams'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,580 - call returned (0, '1005')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,581 - User['ams'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1005}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,582 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,583 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh tez'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,591 - call returned (0, '1006')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,591 - User['tez'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'users'], 'uid': 1006}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,593 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,593 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh zeppelin'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,602 - call returned (0, '1007')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,603 - User['zeppelin'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'zeppelin', u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1007}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,604 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,604 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh accumulo'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,612 - call returned (0, '1008')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,612 - User['accumulo'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1008}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,613 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,614 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh livy'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,622 - call returned (0, '1009')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,623 - User['livy'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1009}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,624 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,624 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh spark'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,633 - call returned (0, '1010')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,633 - User['spark'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1010}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,634 - User['ambari-qa'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'users'], 'uid': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,636 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,637 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh hdfs'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,645 - call returned (0, '1012')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,645 - User['hdfs'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1012}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,648 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,649 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh yarn'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,656 - call returned (0, '1013')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,657 - User['yarn'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1013}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,658 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,658 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh mapred'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,667 - call returned (0, '1014')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,667 - User['mapred'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1014}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,669 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,669 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh knox'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,678 - call returned (0, '1015')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,678 - User['knox'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1015}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,679 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,680 - call['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh hcat'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,688 - call returned (0, '1016')
2018-08-22 20:06:47,690 - User['hcat'] {'gid': 'hadoop', 'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop'], 'uid': 1016}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,691 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh'] {'content': StaticFile('changeToSecureUid.sh'), 'mode': 0555}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,692 - Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa 0'] {'not_if': '(test $(id -u ambari-qa) -gt 1000) || (false)'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,698 - Skipping Execute['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/changeUid.sh ambari-qa /tmp/hadoop-ambari-qa,/tmp/hsperfdata_ambari-qa,/home/ambari-qa,/tmp/ambari-qa,/tmp/sqoop-ambari-qa 0'] due to not_if
2018-08-22 20:06:47,698 - Group['hdfs'] {}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,699 - User['hdfs'] {'fetch_nonlocal_groups': True, 'groups': [u'hadoop', u'hdfs']}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,700 - FS Type: 
2018-08-22 20:06:47,700 - Directory['/etc/hadoop'] {'mode': 0755}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,714 - File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hadoop-env.sh'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,714 - Directory['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/hadoop_java_io_tmpdir'] {'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 01777}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,728 - Execute[('setenforce', '0')] {'not_if': '(! which getenforce ) || (which getenforce && getenforce | grep -q Disabled)', 'sudo': True, 'only_if': 'test -f /selinux/enforce'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,732 - Skipping Execute[('setenforce', '0')] due to not_if
2018-08-22 20:06:47,733 - Directory['/var/log/hadoop'] {'owner': 'root', 'create_parents': True, 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0775, 'cd_access': 'a'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,736 - Directory['/var/run/hadoop'] {'owner': 'root', 'create_parents': True, 'group': 'root', 'cd_access': 'a'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,738 - Directory['/tmp/hadoop-hdfs'] {'owner': 'hdfs', 'create_parents': True, 'cd_access': 'a'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,741 - File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/commons-logging.properties'] {'content': Template('commons-logging.properties.j2'), 'owner': 'hdfs'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,743 - File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/health_check'] {'content': Template('health_check.j2'), 'owner': 'hdfs'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,749 - File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/log4j.properties'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0644}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,758 - File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/hadoop-metrics2.properties'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,759 - File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/task-log4j.properties'] {'content': StaticFile('task-log4j.properties'), 'mode': 0755}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,760 - File['/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf/configuration.xsl'] {'owner': 'hdfs', 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,763 - File['/etc/hadoop/conf/topology_mappings.data'] {'owner': 'hdfs', 'content': Template('topology_mappings.data.j2'), 'only_if': 'test -d /etc/hadoop/conf', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0644}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,767 - File['/etc/hadoop/conf/topology_script.py'] {'content': StaticFile('topology_script.py'), 'only_if': 'test -d /etc/hadoop/conf', 'mode': 0755}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,936 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client/conf
2018-08-22 20:06:47,937 - Directory['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'create_parents': True, 'mode': 0755}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,939 - Directory['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'create_parents': True, 'mode': 0700}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,939 - XmlConfig['accumulo-site.xml'] {'group': 'hadoop', 'conf_dir': '/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server', 'mode': 0600, 'configuration_attributes': {}, 'owner': 'accumulo', 'configurations': ...}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,948 - Generating config: /usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/accumulo-site.xml
2018-08-22 20:06:47,948 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/accumulo-site.xml'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0600, 'encoding': 'UTF-8'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,960 - Directory['/var/run/accumulo'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'create_parents': True, 'mode': 0755, 'cd_access': 'a'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,961 - Directory['/var/log/accumulo'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'create_parents': True, 'mode': 0755, 'cd_access': 'a'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,965 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/accumulo-env.sh'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0644}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,966 - PropertiesFile['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/client.conf'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'properties': {'instance.zookeeper.host': u'geomesa-master-0:2181,geomesa-master-1:2181,geomesa-master-2:2181', 'instance.name': u'hdp-accumulo-instance', 'instance.zookeeper.timeout': u'30s'}}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,968 - Generating properties file: /usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/client.conf
2018-08-22 20:06:47,969 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/client.conf'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,971 - Writing File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/client.conf'] because contents don't match
2018-08-22 20:06:47,972 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/log4j.properties'] {'content': ..., 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0644}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,972 - TemplateConfig['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/auditLog.xml'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'template_tag': None, 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,974 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/auditLog.xml'] {'content': Template('auditLog.xml.j2'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,975 - TemplateConfig['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/generic_logger.xml'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'template_tag': None, 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,977 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/generic_logger.xml'] {'content': Template('generic_logger.xml.j2'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,978 - TemplateConfig['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/monitor_logger.xml'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'template_tag': None, 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,980 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/monitor_logger.xml'] {'content': Template('monitor_logger.xml.j2'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,980 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/accumulo-metrics.xml'] {'content': StaticFile('accumulo-metrics.xml'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0644}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,981 - TemplateConfig['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/tracers'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'template_tag': None, 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,982 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/tracers'] {'content': Template('tracers.j2'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,983 - TemplateConfig['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/gc'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'template_tag': None, 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,984 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/gc'] {'content': Template('gc.j2'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,985 - TemplateConfig['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/monitor'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'template_tag': None, 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,986 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/monitor'] {'content': Template('monitor.j2'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,987 - TemplateConfig['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/slaves'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'template_tag': None, 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,988 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/slaves'] {'content': Template('slaves.j2'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,989 - TemplateConfig['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/masters'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'template_tag': None, 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,990 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/masters'] {'content': Template('masters.j2'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,991 - TemplateConfig['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/hadoop-metrics2-accumulo.properties'] {'owner': 'accumulo', 'template_tag': None, 'group': 'hadoop'}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,995 - File['/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server/hadoop-metrics2-accumulo.properties'] {'content': Template('hadoop-metrics2-accumulo.properties.j2'), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': None}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,996 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/cmds'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0600}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,997 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/pass0'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0600}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,998 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/pass'] {'content': InlineTemplate(...), 'owner': 'accumulo', 'group': 'hadoop', 'mode': 0600}
2018-08-22 20:06:47,999 - Execute['cat /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/pass | ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server /usr/hdp/current/accumulo-client/bin/accumulo shell -u root -f /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/cmds'] {'not_if': 'ambari-sudo.sh su accumulo -l -s /bin/bash -c \'cat /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/pass0 | ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server /usr/hdp/current/accumulo-client/bin/accumulo shell -u root -e "userpermissions -u ambari-qa"\'', 'user': 'accumulo'}

Command failed after 1 tries
```

When I run this manually, both the normal accumulo shell and the `ambari-sudo` in the `not_if` block this is what I see

```
accumulo@geomesa-slave-0:/var/lib/ambari-agent$ cat /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/pass | ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR=/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-tracer/conf/server /usr/hdp/current/accumulo-client/bin/accumulo shell -u root -f /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/cmds
Password: ******************************************
2018-08-28 19:49:49,823 [trace.DistributedTrace] INFO : SpanReceiver org.apache.accumulo.tracer.ZooTraceClient was loaded successfully.
2018-08-28 19:49:49,837 [impl.ServerClient] WARN : There are no tablet servers: check that zookeeper and accumulo are running.
```

I see Zookeeper being online and available as I have connected the Accumulo TServers to it and they are working.. Perhaps I am missing something in my Accumulo setup. Maybe I am wrong in thinking the TServers are working correctly or there is some misconfiguration. But everything seems correct and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong to setup the Tracers. Any help in debugging this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely culprit is incorrect configuration. The `accumulo-tracer` service reads the `conf/accumulo-site.xml` file for its configuration. In particular, pay attention to the `trace.user` and either the `trace.password` or the `trace.token.type` and `trace.token.property.*` fields to construct a valid trace `AuthenticationToken`.

See the [user manual](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.9/accumulo_user_manual#TRACE_PREFIX) for information about these properties.

If using Kerberos, refer to [this section](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.9/accumulo_user_manual#_server_configuration_2) regarding configuring the tracer service's credentials.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the post I inherited this accumulo & zookeeper setup and I'm very new to accumulo. Where is this accumulo tracer password actually being created? Like was a password created in zookeeper or the tablet servers beforehand? I assumed that the password was set correctly but it might not be. If I need to change it how do I go about that?